# How to run Identity Server V3 client examples

Tags: identityserver3

I'm trying to run some of the examples [from here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients). They're configured to access `localhost:44333` - if I run one of the examples, e.g. JavascriptResourceOwner, the calls to that address are not getting any response. What project/solution should I be running on that port?

Answer (score 0):

You should run IdentityServer in separate solution for example from example 
[IdentityServer3.AspNetIdentity](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.AspNetIdentity)

Answer (score 0):

All client samples are designed to be run with the core project host:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3